# Node modules are not install in node packages

Tags: angular, npm

When I enter the `ng serve` command in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
 10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html                                                               92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\popper.js\dist\umd\popper.min.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:436:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:341:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:134:44)
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:42:54)
    at Promise (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:69:49)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at scripts.map.fullPath (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:68:24)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at hook (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\startup\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\ATM-Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:67:43)
```

I have used these commands to install the needed dependencies:

```
npm install jquery -- save
npm install jquery -- save
npm i @angular-devkit/build-webpack
```

And also tried this as well in `angular.json`:

```
“styles": [
  “src/styles.css",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  “./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  “./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  “./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

But none of them have fixed the error.

Please someone can help me?

Comment: Please **don’t** mix jQuery with Angular. Instead, since you’re using Bootstrap, I suggest that you use the [`ngx-bootstrap` library](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/).

Comment: Please show your package.json and index.html

Comment: Are you sure you’re using the correct type of double quotation mark for the last code  sample (the `angular.json` snippet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running below command:

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

The error clears states `404` for `node_modules\popper.js\dist\umd\popper.min.js` path.